# Center a div in CSS

Tags: css, html, center

I'm trying to center a `<div>` horizontally.

I already have `text-align: center;` on the `<div>` itself, but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `text-align: center;` only centers the element's **inline contents**, not the element itself.

If it is a [*block* element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) (a `div` is), you need to set `margin: 0 auto;`, else if it is an [*inline* element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html), you need to set the `text-align: center;` on its *parent* element instead.

The `margin: 0 auto;` will set top and bottom margin to `0` and left and right margin to `auto` (of the same size) so that it automagically puts itself in the center. This only works if the block element in question has a known `width` (either fixed or relative), else it cannot figure where to start and end.

Comment: and you might have to give the "div" an explicit width as well.

Comment: Yes, you indeed need to give the block element an explicit width as well, I edited it in.

Comment: IIRC, some older versions of IE will not recognize `auto` margin values, but they *will* (erroneously) use `text-align` to center block elements, so use both if you can.

Comment: @T. Yates: Nobody uses IE5 or older (read: it works perfectly fine in IE6 which is considered as the **absolute** minimum you (probably) would like to support).

Comment: does it work on Chrome? 'cause in my Chrome it doesn't make text inside my div to align to the center.

Comment: @Bak: you actually need `text-align: center` for that. Just ask a new question if you stucks.

Comment: `text-align: center;` works perfectly with `inline-block` elements. This is the only answer that worked for me

Comment: You might need `float: none;` as well.

Comment: @intrepidis: nope.

Comment: @BalusC Yep. It didn't work for us unless we added `float: none;`. My company still use IE 11 in some quarters.

Comment: @intrepidis: It's only needed if `float` is inherited from a parent which has (incorrectly) set it to a non-`none` value. If this wasn't present in first place, then it's not needed at all. In other words, it's by default not needed at all.

Answer (score 6):

text-align should not be used to center a block element. (except in IE6, but this is a [bug](http://haslayout.net/css/Text-Align-Bug))

You have to fix the width of the block, then use margin: 0 auto;

```
#block
{
   width: 200px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and

```
<div id="#block">Some text... Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**One way :**

```
<div align="center">you content</div>
```

**Better way:**

```
<div id="myDiv">you content</div>
```

CSS for myDIV:

```
#myDiv{
margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided width is set, and you put a proper DOCTYPE,

Try this:

```
 Margin-left: auto;
 Margin-right: auto;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For a cleaner look for the developers, use only 'margin: 0 auto;'

Answer (score 1):

add

```
margin:auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

i always use

```
<div align="center">Some contents......</div>
```

Comment: I confirm that this works with Firefox(v54), Chrome(v58) and Safari(v10).

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-align: center` for the container, `display: inline-block` for the wrapper div, and `display: inline` for the content div to horizontally center content that has an undefined width across browsers:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">

    /* Use inline-block for the wrapper */
    .wrapper { display: inline-block; }

    .content { display:inline; }

    .container { text-align:center; }

    /*Media query for IE7 and under*/

    @media,
      {
      .wrapper { display:inline; }
      }
        </style>

        <title>Horizontal Centering Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="wrapper">
              test text
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the style.

```
margin-left: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#bottombox {
background:transparent url(../images/bg-bottombox.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
float:none;
height:137px;
margin:0 auto;
padding-top:14px;
width:296px;
}
```

That should center the div in your footer.

Answer (score -2):

Create a table with single row and three columns, set left and right width to 100% and voila, the middle one gets centered automatically

Comment: This is a valid answer. Impractical in most scenarios, yes. HOWEVER, still valid. Please stop downvoting a valid answer just because you 'feel like it.'