# How do I center a <table>?

Tags: php, html, css

I want my table centered so I tried this: `<table align=center>HEEHHE</table>` which doesn't work.

My code:

```
<?php
$servername = "***:3306";
$username = "**";
$password = "!!!!";
$dbname = "***";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT balance FROM tbl_users WHERE userID = 8";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table align="center"><tr><th>Aktuell im Jackpot:</tr></th>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["balance"]."</tr></td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Your code would return a syntax error, because you close your string, followed directly by "center". Change that to `align='center'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center a div in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281087/center-a-div-in-css)

Comment: Read the MattDiMu's comment about issues in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align="center"` will probably still work, even though it's a deprecated attribute (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). You should probably use CSS for styling, e.g. `table { margin: 0 auto; }` should do it.

You have multiple issues in your code though:

- the `tr` is closed before the `th` element (see below for the right
  structure)
- the `td` is closed before the `th element` (see below)
- double quote syntax error (as hinted by Audite Marlow)

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Aktuell im Jackpot:</th></tr>
<tr><td>1231234</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<table height="100%" width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle">
<p>Content</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There are some error's:

```
echo "<table align="center"><tr><th>Aktuell im Jackpot:**</th></tr>**";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["balance"]."**</td></tr>**";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is wrong:

```
echo "<table align="center"><tr><th>Aktuell im Jackpot:</tr></th>"; // wrong code
```

You should escape quotation marks: \"center\"; Or use single quotes like `echo '<table style="margin: 0 auto;">...</table>';`.

Well, it has a better way you stylize things, but I'm going straight to the point: instead `align="center"`, **use** `style="margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;"`.

If you need to center in vertical, this guide is good for you: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Thank you!! 1000 +